# Superintuitionistic logics weaker then classical logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I want to construct an example of a superintuitionistic logic which is a strict superset of $\operatorname{Int}$ and a strict subset of $\operatorname{Cl}$. I think that such logic can be obtained by adding formulas of the form $\lor_{1 \leq i < j \leq n+1}(p_i \leftrightarrow p_j)$. I can show that such logics are stronger than $\operatorname{Int}$ by constructing Kripke models in which such additional formulas are not satisficed. But are such extensions weaker than $\operatorname{Cl}$ and if yes, how I can prove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of intermediate logics strictly between IPC and CPC (actually continuum many, by Jankov Theorem). If you are looking for examples, you can check logics such as KP, which is obtained from IPC by adding the axiom scheme $(\neg x\to(y\lor z)) \to ((\neg x\to y) \lor (\neg x \to z))$, or WEM, which is obtained by adding $\neg x \lor \neg\neg x$ or others.

Coming to your example, if I do understand correctly you are defining $\omega$-many extensions $L_n$ of IPC. Fix some $n$, then for some $p_i$ we have that $\bigvee_{i\neq j\leq n} (p_i\leftrightarrow p_j)\in L_n$. Since  super intuitionistic logics are closed under uniform substitution, we obtain, by the map $p_j\mapsto \neg p_i$, that   $\bigvee_{i\neq j\leq n} (p_i\leftrightarrow \neg p_i )\in L_n$ meaning that $L_n$ is inconsistent and thus $\text{CPC}\subseteq L_n$.

Comment: No. $L_1$ is inconsistent, but all $L_n$ for $n\geq2$ are consistent (and included in classical logic).  In fact, $L_2$ is equivalent to classical logic, while $L_3,L_4,\dots$ are weaker.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I still do not see where is the mistake in my reasoning though. Could you elaborate why $L_n$ is consistent, for $n\geq2$?

Comment: The formulas $\bigvee_{i\neq j\le n}(p_i\leftrightarrow p_j$ are tautologies. The mistake in your argument is that you gave a substitution falsifying one of the disjuncts, but you'd have to falsify all the disjuncts simultaneously in order to falsify the disjunction.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Can you help me see why $L_2$ is $Cl$ and $L_3$ is weaker?

Comment: @GlebChili $L_2$ says "of any three truth values, some two are equal". If you instantiate one $p_i$ as "true" and another s "false", it tells you that the remaining $p_i$ is true or false. Similarly $L_3$ says "of any four truth values, some two are equal," which holds in classical logic but also in Heyting algebras of size $3$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the comment. I got confused with the indices of the disjunction. So for $L_2$, for example, we should obtain, by uniform substitution, $p_1\leftrightarrow \top \lor p_1 \leftrightarrow \bot \lor \top\leftrightarrow\bot \in L_2$, meaning $L_2$ contains excluded middle.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It seems like I need to learn about Heyting algebras semantics, in course I'm taking we are working only with Kripke semantics. Am I right that formal proof for case $L_3$ is looking something like that: $L_3$ is sound with respect to Heyting algebras of size 3, but such structures do not satisfy the law of excluded middle?

Comment: @GlebChili Heyting algebras are to intuitionistic logic as Boolean algebras are to classical logic. In particular, intuitionistic logic is valid in all Heyting algebras. Boolean algebras are special Heyting algebras, but there are many other Heyting algebras that are not Boolean and thus don't satisfy classical logic.